# Can't Remove Item from Array

Tags: .net, arrays, powershell

I'm trying to remove items from an array, but no matter what method I use, it doesn't seem to be working.  I need some help wrapping my head around whats happening here.

I normally default to using [System.Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) but that doesn't work, and I [now understand why](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.isfixedsize(v=vs.110).aspx):

```psh
[array]$arrADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 7 Enterprise" ' -Properties Name | select name
$arrADComputers.GetType()
$arrADComputers.count
$arrADComputers.Remove("Machine")
$arrADComputers.count
```

So I'm instead trying with [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx), but that doesn't work either.

```psh
$Collection1 = {$arrADComputers}.Invoke()
$Collection1.GetType()
$Collection1.Count
$Collection1.Remove("Machine")
$Collection1.count
```

The same is also true with [System.Collections.ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

```psh
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Collection2 = $arrADComputers
$Collection2.GetType()
$Collection2.Count
$Collection2.Remove("Machine")
$Collection2.count
```

But if I create an array like so, it works correctly:

```psh
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Trash1 = 1,"this",2,"that",3,"them","4"
$Trash1.GetType()
$Trash1.Count
$Trash1.Remove("that")
$Trash1.Count

$TrashTmp = 1,"this",2,"that",3,"them","4"
$Trash2 = {$TrashTmp}.Invoke()
$Trash2.GetType()
$Trash2.Count
$Trash2.Remove("that")
$Trash2.Count
```

What concept am I not grasping that's preventing me from removing items from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type from `Get-ADComputer` is `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer]`, not a `[String]`, so you can't just remove a computer by giving its name.

You could iterate over the collection and remove it if its name property matches, but you'd be better off filtering before with `Where-Object` or with the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ADComputer`.

If all you care about are the computer names, then make the arraylist with the names only:

```powershell
$Collection = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
$Collection.Remove('ComputerName')
```

This should work, because now the arraylist is all strings (just the names).

Comment: If the `ADComputer` objects are required for further processing, a hashtable with the computer names as keys could be used instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the explanation and solution.  This makes more sense and now it works as expected.

`[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 7 Enterprise"' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name;$arrADComputers.Count;$arrADComputers.Remove("machine1");$arrADComputers.Count`


Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

@briantist gave the actual problem here, that being the fact that you do not have an array of strings, you have an array of ADComputer objects. As such when you try to remove the string "machine" it can't find that. A somewhat hackish work around for this is to rebuild your array excluding the target object in order to remove that one ADComputer object. Something like this:

```psh
[array]$arrADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 7 Enterprise" ' -Properties Name | select name
$arrADComputers.GetType()
$arrADComputers.count
$arrADComputers = $arrADComputers | Where{$_.samaccountname -ne "machine"}
$arrADComputers.count
```

Alternatively you could find the object that you want to remove, and then use the `Remove()` method like you were before, something like:

```psh
[array]$arrADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 7 Enterprise" ' -Properties Name | select name
$arrADComputers.GetType()
$arrADComputers.count
$objComputer = $arrADComputers | Where{$_.samaccountname -eq "machine"}
$arrADComputers.Remove($objComputer)
$arrADComputers.count
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the hackish workaround :)  I had considered doing something like that but in my mind I was just working around a gap in knowledge.  Still, works nonetheless!  Again, I greatly appreciate the explanation.